# Why is my program giving weird results?

Tags: c++

The following snippets are the header file and the actual `main()` function. I am using Visual Studio 2017 with Windows 10.

**.h**

```
#ifndef SALES_DATA_H
#define SALES_DATA_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Sales_data
{
    int amount;
    int rate;
    int price = amount * rate;
};
#endif
```

**.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sales_data.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Sales_data item1;
    cout << "Enter rate and amount" << endl;
    cin >> item1.rate >> item1.amount;
    cout << item1.price << endl;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

It keeps showing this as the output: "687194768".

I also tried initializing the variables but it does not seem to work.

Comment: `int price = amount * rate;` is done at initialization only, it is not updated when other members changes, you probably want a function instead.

Comment: Just a bit of style advice: That header doesn't use anything from the `<iostream>` header, so the `#include` is not needed. And `using namespace std;` is an abomination, and should not be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably want is:

```
struct Sales_data
{
    int amount = 0;
    int rate = 0;

    int price() const { return amount * rate; }
};
```

And then

```
std::in >> item1.rate >> item1.amount;
std::cout << item1.price() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Price here is being calculated only at initialisation time to get its initial value, however since `amount` and `rate` have not been initialised yet, the result is *undefined*.
*It is not* a  function.

```
struct Sales_data
{
    int amount;
    int rate;
    int price = amount * rate;
};
```

You most likely wanted a function, e.g.:

```
struct Sales_data
{
    int amount;
    int rate;
    int calcPrice()
    {
        return = amount * rate;
    }
};


std::cout << item1.calcPrice() << std::endl;
```

Or you would have to refactor to initialise `amount` and `rate` to make use of such syntax, e.g. with a constructor.

```
struct Sales_data
{
    int amount;
    int rate;
    int price = amount * rate;
    Sales_data(int amount, int rate) : amount(amount), rate(rate) {}
};


Sales_data x(10, 5);
//x.price == 50
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason the code is printing that is because you are calculating that price with uninitialized variables...

define a function in the struct and call it after the input is given

```
void calculatePrice() {
    price = amount * rate;
}

cin >> item1.rate >> item1.amount;
item1.calculatePrice();
cout << item1.price << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, your definition for `Sales_data` uses `amount` or `rate` before they were ever initialised. This is undefined behaviour, and your compiler is more or less free to do whatever it pleases with this.

Many compilers will initialise variables with some sort of recognisable guard value (a popular choice is 0xDEADBEEF) as a way to make it quite obvious when a value is uninitialised when looking at it with a debugger. In this case, it looks like your compiler uses 0xCCCCCCCC as that guard value:

`(lldb) p (int) 0xcccccccc * (int) 0xcccccccc
(int) $2 = 687194768`